# Repeat HTML table row with unique data N times using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I’ve been thrown into a project that uses XSLT 1.0 to query a database, then transform the queried XML data to HTML in one fell swoop. This is the first time I’ve been exposed to XSLT.

My objective is get a list of rooms and find out who is currently in each room. I have to use two different queries, one to get the rooms, and another to get a list of people that are currently in a room. The second query also pulls data from a people-room join table.
The XML comes out as this:

```
 <DATASETLIST>
        <DATASET entity=”ROOM” >
            <ROW>
                <ROOM_ID>
                <ROOM_Name>
                <ROOM_Occupancy>
                <ROOM_OccupantCount>
            </ROW>
        <DATASET entity= “BOOKING;PERSON”>
            <ROW>
                <BOOKING_ID>
                <BOOKING_PERSON_ID>
                <BOOKING_ROOM_ID>
                <DATASET entity=”PERSON”>
                    <ROW>
                        …. PERSON INFO
                    </ROW>
                </DATASET>                      
            </ROW>
        </DATASET>
    </DATASETLIST>
```

Each room number has a letter and number in it. For instance A1, A2, B1, B2, etc.  One of the requirements is to group them by letter which I’ve done using Muenchian grouping.

Then, I’ve iterated through the list of rooms for each group. So, I’m creating an HTML table of each room and it’s corresponding occupant.

```
BLOCK A
    Room #      Person        Misc Person Info
    A1          Smith, Joe    blah, blah
```

I’m using the following code to match the person to the room:

```
<table>
    <xsl:for-each select=”$blocks” > (variable holds the grouping results)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select=”ROOM_ID” />
            </td>
            <xsl:for-each select=”//*[BOOKING__ROOM_ID = current()/ROOM__Id]” >
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/DATASET/ROW/PERSON_Name" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="current()/DATASET/ROW/PERSON_Info" />
            </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

This works, but the problem I’m having is that some rooms can more than one occupant. So the table data puts two people on one line and messes up the format for the table. 
I’ve tried calling a template recursively to create a row for each occupancy slot in a room, however this made a copy of the people as well.

All of this is run and displayed within the vendor's program. The SQL query is a proprietary dialect of SQL-92 so the data must be queried a certain way and the XML results are immutable (as far as I can gather).  Using XSLT, how can I list each room and, if there is more than one occupant in a room, list that room N times with each unique person’s info?

Comment: I guess that you could be helped, but your code is no complete [mcve]. So despite your good description we would have to guess what the input and desired output is...

Comment: So what is the problem you need help with, a different HTML table format that doesn't look messy or a change of the XSLT code to work differently (but in what way) when you have more than one occupant of a room? And are you sure you use an XSLT 1 processor? As you show `<xsl:value-of select="current()/DATASET/ROW/PERSON_Name" />` which with an XSLT 1 processor would only output the first select `PERSON_Name` element I don't understand from your explanation why you get "two people on one line", that would only occur with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.